Looking for a movie about humans being cloned to mine but are unaware
This was mentioned in a side conversation and this sounds interesting. Basically, it's a movie where humans (who are actually clones) are mining extraterrestrially.
Whenever one of them dies, they're replaced by a clone of themselves. The clones aren't aware of them being clones. Memories are used from family members to assist in creating a realistic view for the clones.

Do you have more details on when you watched it, when it may have been released or anything?

Initially sounded like Moon, then you said minded extraterrestrials, so now not sure. In Moon the clones are in a mining operation, the fake recordings are of their family communicating with the original

Are you talking about Moon?  Though there's only really one clone at a time.  (Until, of course, there aren't...)

It sounds like you're describing Moon (2009).
The protagonist, Sam, is working on the moon, supervising a gang of robotic mining 'harvesters' that are tasked with collecting Helium-3. Unbeknownst to Sam, he's actually a clone, the latest in a series of clones that are periodically replaced by an evil corporation. He is fed a series of pre-recorded videotapes of his wife and family in order to keep him motivated.




GERTY was great, like Rethink Robotics' "Baxter" with actual AI. (Sadly Rethink Robotics shut down. It lost the market fight against Universal Robots.

There's a new movie coming out called Mickey 17 where the main character is an "expendable" - a clone with preserved memories that is employed in dangerous work and replaced with a new clone each time he is killed.



